# How to put an input after a loop have ended?

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop

```
counter=0
actual_password="hi"
enter_password=''
while enter_password!=actual_password and counter<3:
    enter_password=raw_input("pls enter pass")
    if enter_password==actual_password:
        print "well done"
    else:
        print "try again"
        counter += 1
```

How to print bye at the end of loop after three tries?

Answer (score 2):

This may help ... simple `if` statement.

```
counter=0
actual_password="hi"
enter_password=''
while enter_password!=actual_password and counter<3:
    enter_password=raw_input("pls enter pass")
    if enter_password==actual_password:
        print "well done"
    else:
        counter += 1
        if counter == 3:
            print 'bye'
            break
        print "try again"
```

Comment: move the `if counter == 3` out of the while

Comment: Oh..I did that somebody edited that..its edited again. @LittleQ

Comment: Edited the code again. It is possible now. You may accept it ... if it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Check `counter` to decide what to print:

```
else:
    counter += 1
    if counter < 3:
        print "try again"
    else:
        print "bye"
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of problem is well suited to using a `for` loop. This would print "bye" after the three tries, or if the user enters the correct password.

```
actual_password = "hi"

for tries in range(3):
    enter_password = raw_input("pls enter pass: ")

    if enter_password == actual_password:
        print "well done"
        break
    print "try again"

print "bye"
```